# How can we motivate 3k+ users to do reviews?

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-close

It has been a little while since our site had been promoted with a new design and thresholds for privileges have been raised alongside.

Now what I have seen is that the "Close votes" review queue has been filling up with at least 10+ up to 40+ close votes awaiting review. Before the site promotion, users of 500+ reputation could vote on close votes, now this has been raised to 3k+ reputation, which means before there were **over 300 users** that were able to vote and right now there are **only [45 users with over 3k+](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)** that can vote.

Some people are even calling upon the Romanian army...

[image]

Ok, 10 to 40 queued reviews is nothing compared to the numbers seen on StackOverflow, I know. But if we need the powers of one man to solve this, then I would not call this a community effort.

**Come on people of 3k+, vote!**

**UPDATE:**

I thought, ok maybe a lot of those 3k+ users aren't active? (maybe now after this post and the tweets... :P). So I checked, doing some jQuery and Ajax on the users page and that is clearly not the case:

```
Marius                      Last seen 15 mins ago
Amit Bera                   Last seen 8 mins ago
Sander Mangel               Last seen 4 hours ago
philwinkle                  Last seen 14 hours ago
Fabian Blechschmidt         Last seen 22 hours ago
fschmengler                 Last seen 3 mins ago
 ---  <20k  ---
David Manners               Last seen yesterday
Alan Storm                  Last seen 14 hours ago
Ben Lessani - Sonassi       Last seen yesterday
benmarks                    Last seen yesterday
Anna Völkl                  Last seen yesterday
 ---  <10k  ---
Qaisar Satti                Last seen 41 mins ago
Rajeev K Tomy               Last seen yesterday
Tim Bezhashvyly             Last seen yesterday
Vinai                       Last seen 2 days ago
R.S                         Last seen 2 days ago
Alex                        Last seen yesterday
Kristof at Fooman           Last seen yesterday
ProxiBlue                   Last seen 3 hours ago
Vladimir Kerkhoff           Last seen 2 days ago
Raphael at Digital Pianism  Last seen 10 mins ago
davidalger                  Last seen Mar 28 at 18:56 <---
B00MER                      Last seen 50 mins ago
Keyul Shah                  Last seen 7 hours ago
Matthias Zeis               Last seen 3 hours ago
 ---  <5k  ---
mbalparda                   Last seen 51 mins ago
KAndy                       Last seen 20 hours ago
MeenakshiSundaram R         Last seen yesterday
mageUz                      Last seen Apr 4 at 7:30
Alex Paliarush              Last seen 21 hours ago
Pradeep Sanku               Last seen Apr 4 at 16:09
Amasty                      Last seen Feb 10 at 10:24 <---
Fiasco Labs                 Last seen 2 days ago
Sukeshini                   Last seen 3 hours ago
Flyingmana                  Last seen 17 hours ago
oleksii.svarychevskyi       Last seen Mar 17 at 8:55 <---
musicliftsme                Last seen 22 hours ago
moose                       Last seen 1 hour ago
Simon                       Last seen 1 hour ago
Jonathan Hussey             Last seen 3 hours ago
Abdul                       Last seen 3 hours ago
Adarsh Khatri               Last seen yesterday
TBI Infotech                Last seen Mar 1 at 8:39 <---
brentwpeterson              Last seen yesterday
Keyur Shah                  Last seen 6 mins ago
```

Comment: I guess we have to bring in the Romanian army then. Never question Ben's decisions.

Comment: I used to quite enjoy plodding through the review queues. Now I need to scrape together another few thousand rep before I can do anything useful again. *sigh*

Comment: Just like @LukeRodgers I had no problem going through that queue and was happy to do so. Now every time I hit the "Review" button I see the close vote queue greyed out with 10+ votes awaiting. That just makes me sad. Why was that threshold raised that high in the first place?

Comment: For me, the quality of questions on the site in more recent times has really put me off being more active on SE.  To my mind the vast majority of questions are highly store specific 'this or that is broken' and often require significant time spent to debug and properly answer.  I just don't have the kind of time to solve other peoples very store specific development issues.  What I do have time for, and enjoy doing, is writing complete, accurate answers describing core framework functionality.  Unfortunately very few questions that I see these days allow for that.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than organizing a MageStackDay again (I hope [Anna](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/231/anna-v%C3%B6lkl) and [Sander](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50/sander-mangel) don't kill me for this) I see no other way.
The StackExchange network already has incentives for this:

- [Custodian](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges/82/custodian)
- [Reviewer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges/78/reviewer)
- [Steward](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges/83/steward)
- a few other badges in the "[Moderation Badges](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/badges)" section.

If people don't want to contribute you cannot force them.

Comment: Anna told me they may have another one this year on the Mage Slack. Or maybe it was in my dream, not sure. Are vote limitations rised up during MageStackDay ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism. No. The limits stay the same, because MSD is not an official SE event. But during the event people get more involved and other people get a chance to reach  3k points.

Answer (score 6):

Agreed with you, I very often run out of close votes. Sometimes I see people like you, Marius, Fabian and myself have already used 20 close votes and I still see a 10+ long review queue.

I reckon the problem is **not only the number of people who can vote to close** but **also the number of questions related to 3rd party modules** that make that number of posts to close very high. Maybe it's just the way I see things I'd be interested to see the percentage of closed posts where the reason is "3rd party modules questions are off-topic".

Can we actually get that info via the data SE ?

We can get some distribution here but not sure if we can get more details than this: https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/17934/distribution-of-close-reasons.

[image]

I assume:

- 101 => duplicate
- 102 => off-topic
- 103 => unclear
- 104 => too broad
- 105 => opinion based

People seem to ignore the fact that questions about 3rd party modules are off-topic, maybe we should find a way to make that clearer I'm not sure.

Ended up finding the data re: close reasons over the last 90 days it's available for 10k users here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days

**3rd party module reason is 30% !!**

Comment: Your assumption is correct, see `CloseReasonTypes`. There is also `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes` with 7 being the 3rd party module reason. I'm trying to come up with a query for that one.

Comment: I don't know if we have access to it, but I recall on the StackOverflow podcast one of the Product team guys talking about a feature they developed that could provide some kind of interactive feedback during the submission of a question based on certain criteria.  They were talking about using it to do things when there was either no code sample included in a question vs. when there was too much code.  If we could leverage that feature to scan for verbiage that was common in those 1076 questions or the subset that was specifically flagged for 3rd party extns we could reduce the review load

Comment: @fschmengler ended up finding out everything was here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days

Comment: @raphael On a side note, how are you able to do 20 review task for 1st post almost every day? I go the the review queue about 12 times a day, and almost never see one there. Are you bored and thus refresh the page every 3 seconds or are you being crafty about this?

Comment: @JulienLachal my finger is on repeat on the F5 key that's all I do all day long ^^ lol just kidding: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-monitor/ogeebjpdeabhncjpfhgdibjajcajepgg?hl=en

Comment: I thought you'd have better things to do that refresh all day long too :p. Well I'm just sad I'm not able to review anymore, but as long as you get the job done in the end, it's all that matters!

Comment: @JulienLachal I've taken your feedback into consideration I'll leave the reviews as long as the list is not over 10 pending reviews ;)

Comment: It's cool man, just do it the classic way and go there from time to time. It'll never get to 10 unreviewed 1st post anyways ^^ I suspect others use the same type of plugins.